# Asking questions you know the answer to

Tags: discussion

I was pondering the origins of the phrase "to call a spade a spade" the other night and thought of asking it here but instead Googled it and got the information I wanted.  Even though the information is readily available to any competent web user, should I ask the question here too?  If this is meant to be *the* definitive place to go for answers to English Language questions, shouldn't this be a place where a person could find that information?  Or is it just a festival of redundancy?

(I'm not interested in thoughts on the "spade" question -- this is more a "site philosophy" question.)

Comment: I would say, go on and post it. I was about to compose a more thorough answer rather than this brief comment, but then I realized that I was simply rehashing [what I had said elsewhere](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/162/pointless-questions-and-answers/179#179) (and with which at least six other people agreed).

Answer (score 10):

A good question is not a bad one by virtue of the fact that you personally know the answer. A bonus is that you might learn a facet to the answer you weren't aware of, or you might find out you weren't as right as you thought -- either is an opportunity for you, or for others to learn.

In short: Yes, please, go ahead and post it.

Answer (score 5):

There's another reason for posting questions which are readily googlable (is that a word?). And that is, while an expert may be certain that the answer provided by google is correct, there is plenty of misinformation that can be located by google. Finding it on stack exchange should provide a higher level of assurance. And since a naive user might have trouble distinguishing authorities found by google, it's worthwhile to have it here.